# Is a .GIF better for animation than OpenGL for performance?

Tags: android, opengl-es, xamarin.android

I am making an Android app that requires a wave-like animation like this:

https://github.com/Cleveroad/WaveInApp/blob/master/images/demo_.gif?raw=true

As far as performance, would it be better to use this library (https://github.com/Cleveroad/WaveInApp) that is OpenGL based to have this animation, or use a .GIF (or some sort of series of images) in my App? It might seem obvious that OpenGL computations to create those waves would be more expensive on resources, but I know displaying a series of images in succession would be expensive too, so I would like to make sure. This app is being developed in Xamarin.Android if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely OpenGL will be way faster.  Almost all of Android's views are built on top of OpenGL because it can use hardware for drawing operations which is more efficient than doing it in software.  GIFS would be animated in software so would be slower.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, OpenGL will be faster because it uses the GPU directly, whereas GIFS would use the CPU and would be more work. And do you have any reference to this theory? I need to convince colleagues and look smart at work :)